# How to find at least two non-adjacent pairs of letters

Tags: javascript, regex

Using `'aabcc'.match(/(\w)\1+/g)` I can find repeated pairs of letters. But how can I update my regex to check that they are non-adjacent?
For example:

- This is a good string for me because there are two non-adjacent pairs of letters: `'aabcc'`.
- This one `'aacc'` is not a good string.

Comment: Do you mean to ask for a solution to determine if there are gaps in the letters in the string? The word "overlapping" does not make sense in this context

Comment: His examples suggest he means "adjacent" instead of "overlapping", I edited the question. @rel1x :  Would the aa/cc pair in 'aabbcc' be considered a match since bb separates them?

Comment: Could it be any length, and the pattern is always 22122? Could it be 221221?

Comment: @mhodges I am so sorry, I didn't understand the non-overlapping meaning. my task is to determine that string contains at least two non-overlapping pairs of letters.

Comment: Can you please add more examples of what are "good" and "bad" strings?

Comment: @mhodges  is that means that `aabb` is the string with at least two non-overlapping pairs of letters, and `aab` is not? I am not a native english speaker so `non-overlapping` meaning is hard for me.

Comment: @rel1x: Overlapping means that the start of the next match is somewhere in the middle of the preceding one. Non-overlapping is the opposite. `lal` and `gala` are overlapping in string `galal`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may match a string that only consists of identical consecutive letters and return false then:

```js
function isValid(s) {
  return !/^(?:(\w)\1+)+$/.test(s);
}
console.log(isValid('aabcc'));
console.log(isValid('aacc'));
```

The `^(?:(\w)\1+)+$` matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:(\w)\1+)+` - 1 or more occurrences of:

  - `(\w)` - a word char captured into Group 1
  - `\1+` - 1 or more occurrences of the value stored in Group 1
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: @Tushar Yes, because there is `e` that is not "consecutively repeated".